# How to apply functions iteratively to SpatialLines in R?

Tags: r, intersection, iterator, loop

Looking for a way to apply the 'rgeos::gIntersection' and 'rgeos::gDifference' function iteratively to SpatialLines, I created 3 SpatialLines as an example:

```
#from the sp vignette:
l1 = cbind(c(1,2,3,4),c(3,2,2,4))
rownames(l1) = letters[1:4]
l2 = cbind(c(2,2,3,3),c(3,2,2,5))
rownames(l2) = letters[1:4]
l3 = cbind(c(1,2,3,4),c(1,2,2,1))
rownames(l3) = letters[1:4]
Sl1 = Line(l1)
Sl2 = Line(l2)
Sl3 = Line(l3)
Ll1 = Lines(list(Sl1), ID="a")
Ll2 = Lines(list(Sl2), ID="b")
Ll3 = Lines(list(Sl3), ID="c")
Sl = SpatialLines(list(Ll1,Ll2,Ll3))
summary(Sl)
plot(Sl, col = c("green", "grey", "brown"), lwd=c(10,8,6))
```

How can I do the following lines iteratively (e.g. in a loop)?

```
#Intersection of lines
I12<-gIntersection(Sl[1],Sl[2])
I13<-gIntersection(Sl[1],Sl[3])
I23<-gIntersection(Sl[2],Sl[3])
#plot
lines(I12, lwd=5, col="red")
lines(I13, lwd=3, col="blue")
lines(I23, lwd=1, col="yellow")

#Difference of lines
D12<-gDifference(Sl[1],Sl[2])
D21<-gDifference(Sl[2],Sl[1])
D31<-gDifference(Sl[1],Sl[3])
D31<-gDifference(Sl[3],Sl[1])
D23<-gDifference(Sl[2],Sl[3])
D32<-gDifference(Sl[3],Sl[2])
#plot
lines(D12, lwd=5, col="red")
lines(D13,lwd=3,  col="blue")
lines(D23, lwd=1, col="yellow")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to loop over the combinations you need.

```
> combn(1:length(Sl),2)
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    1    2
[2,]    2    3    3
```

that gets you (in columns) the line indexes. So then do:

```
MyLines = apply(combn(1:length(Sl),2),2,
          function(x){
             gIntersection(Sl[x[1]], Sl[x[2]])
          })
```

Then `MyLines[[1]]` is the intersection of 1 and 2.

For your differences, you want the combinations in both orders.

```
C = combn(1:length(Sl),2)
C2 = cbind(C,C[2:1,])
C2
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
# [1,]    1    1    2    2    3    3
# [2,]    2    3    3    1    1    2

MyDiffs = apply(C2, 2, function(x){gDifference(Sl[x[1]], Sl[x[2]])})
```

The ordering in `MyDiffs` is given by the columns of `C2`. These two are the same geometry:

```
lines(MyDiffs[[1]],lwd=15,col="red")
lines(D12,lwd=4,col="green")
```

Comment: @ Spacedman: Thanks for your answer!  It works fine.

Comment: applying the code shows that gDifferences are build between all lines but should be only created for the intersecting ones. An integration of gIntersects could solve this. How to do this?